# Subdomains to pages

Tags: permalinks, pages, redirect, subdomains

Hi I have a website on wordpress which have 2 pages which I meant to convert it to subdomain.

Eg:  Let my website at be http://www.domain.com

there are two pages http://www.domain.com/page1 and http://www.domain.com/page2

I want them to be accessible at http://page1.domain.com & http://page2.domain.com respectively.

Also I have may subpages to page1 which i wanna access using subdomain of main page. I mean if http://www.domain.com/page1/subpage1 is subpage of http://www.domain.com/page1 then I want to access it as http://page1.domain.com/subpage1

I have already created subdomains in cpanel pointing them to root folder of my website and tried following htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subsite [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subsite/$1 [L]
```

I have tried different other variants of htaccess code I got from different forums and also [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Also tried WP Subdomains (Revisited) plugin and found of no use.

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to use WP_Rewrite for that.

```
add_action('page_rewrite_rules','my_page_rules');
function my_page_rules($rules){
$pageslug = 'sample-page';
$rules['([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?pagename='$pageslug'/$matches[1]';
return $rules;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'sub_page_link');
function sub_page_link(){
// preg_replace here
}
```

I have found a [premium plugin](https://webostock.com/market-item/wordpress-page-as-subdomain-pro/8860/) which uses the same mechanism to convert pages into subdomain, it uses rewrite rules and Server WildCard Configured.

Hope it is helpful!

Comment: Answers should be [more than plain links](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). They should actually be an answer instead of a route where someone will _maybe find_ an answer. Please help preventing link rot, [edit] your answer and provide the needed information that helps the OP as well as later visitors to solve their problem.

Comment: @m-ali-salim I think there may be an error in your code example. What does `$pageslug` resolve to?

Comment: It is just a code snippet to give an idea, you can get page slug using different methods. i.e
$url = getenv( 'HTTP_HOST' );
$domain = explode( ".", $url );
$pageslug = $domain[0];

Comment: Avoid the linked plugin in this answer, "WordPress Page Subdomain Pro" - it's not production suitable and has given us lots of problems. The homepage randomly only redirects to a sub domain, sub domains become randomly inaccessible at points. It's also clear to see that the code is very badly written. Do yourself a favour